# How is the mobility Radeon HD 4670 by today's standards?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, ati-mobility-radeon

I've been reading some reviews, and they seem to be pretty positive for the price, but they all seem to come from early 2008. Is the 4670 still a decent card today? It's the only card offered on the Dell Studio XPS 16, and I'm wondering if I'd be shooting myself in the foot buying it if I want to do some gaming on it (nothing too hardcore, but I'd like to be able to play Starcraft II and Diablo III when they come out).

Comment: FYI Starcraft II & Diablo III are not expected till 2011

Comment: No one has any idea when SCII or DIII are really going to be released, so don't put too much emphasis on a computer choice based on playing those games. Though, Blizzard in the past has been very flexible with most of their game options to run on a wide range of hardware. Reason I say this is I heard the same reasoning being behind people building new computers last year and here we are 1 year later and those games still are not even close to release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Radeon 4670 is pretty good, standing at #29 according to [Notebook check's mobile graphics cards benchmark list](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Mobile-Graphics-Cards-Benchmark-List.844.0.html).
Considering that my 2 year old Inspiron 1520 which features the 8600m GT (#78 on the list, BTW) is pretty good enough to chew whatever I throw at it, you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's pretty decent. Anything much more powerful than that and you're looking at the high-end and dual-GPU kit that will give you a battery life measured in seconds. Laptops+games is always an unhappy trade-off that gets expensive fast.